# What are the columns in a LR Parsing Table?

Tags: parsing, lr-grammar

yep, question is short and sufficiently posed in the title.

**What are the columns in the action-table of a LR(k)-Parsing table?**

Are they the union of all productions' left hand sides' NonTerminals FIRST sets?

Answer (score 1):

The rows are states and the columns are the grammar's terminals; in other words, the "alphabet". Not every symbol is necessarily in a FIRST set, so the union of FIRST sets can be a subset of the alphabet.

The parser also has a somewhat similar GOTO table, whose rows are states and whose columns are non-terminals. Between the two tables, all the grammar's symbols are covered.

Comment: What i meant was that if it is the case that if column c of row q of an LR-parsing table is either one of the two actions "shift" or "reduce", is it then the case that the input symbol of the column c **is in the FOLLOW set of ´dfa-state/itemset "q"´ such that** it can follow `"q"´ either a)  through  a `shift` action or that it can b) follow said state "q" through reduction, i.e. popping off rhs-states and pushing the goto-table entry for the reduced symbol ? With following I mean that the next unread input-symbol (token) is, for instance, the `open brace`

Comment: Since the transition table defines the possible transitions of the DFA, it seems tautological that the set of columns for a row in which there is a non-error action is precisely the set of tokens which can be handled from that state. The common usage of "follow set" is not based on DFA states though. We normally talk about the "follow set" of a non-terminal. (In theory, the concept could apply to a terminal as well.) But follow sets aren't used in LR parsing, except for SLR. Follow sets are used in the construction of an LL parser, but only if there are nullable non-terminals.

Comment: In the LR construction, items (*not* itemsets) are associated with lookahead sets, which are similar to followsets. But note that the lookahead set for an item is the lookahead for the production, not the lookahead at the item's dot. Only when the dot is at the end of an item (indicating the existence of a reduction) does the lookahead set correspond to the lookahead token. A shift action is possible for an item whose dot is followed by a token. A goto action is possible for an item whose dot is followed by a non-terminal. The itemset's actions is the set of actions of the itemset's items.

Comment: First I am glad that you understood my maybe a little encumbering formulated question. But then I wonder how you know, when constructing the table, how to know for which input-character ("Since the transition table defines the possible transitions of the DFA"), say, a `"*"` (star), to formulate, say, a reduce action - knowing that the re-duct (as opposed to product) maybe via a goto instruction will be able to transition to a state, where there is a transition on `"*"(star)` **-while you do not decide for a *reduce-*, but a *shift-* action on input-char, say, `"+ (plus)`. Btw: What is the ...

Comment: ... name for the graph problem that the lr-parsing table solves: finding all possible paths (through the machine states - possibly with circles) from start to accept state ?

Comment: For every item in the itemset, you add the appropriate transition(s): shift if the dot is before a token, goto if the dot is before a non-terminal and reduce (by the item's production) on each token in the item's lookahead if the dot is at the end. For reduce actions you need to know the lookahead set; the dragon book explains the algorithm. If an itemset has more than one transition on the same token, that's a conflict. (Including two reduce actions on the same token to different productions.)

Comment: Differently and more - or most - concise put: Why are there reduce actions in some fields for some columns (input symbols)  - while in other fields for other columns (input symbols) there are shift actions or even none at all.

Comment: I don't think there's an answer other than "that's the way it worked out for this grammar". Every input symbol has a shift action in some state -- otherwise, the symbol cannot be used -- but clearly it's not going to have a shift action in every state (unless the symbol can appear absolutely anywhere, which is uncommon).

Comment: Similarly, there's a reduce action for a symbol if it's in the follow set for a non-terminal, because if a symbol is in a non-terminal's follow set, there must be some sentence in which that non-terminal is followed by that symbol. But not every symbol in a non-terminal's follow set will trigger a reduction with an item for that non-terminal. It might be necessary to perform another reduction first, for example. LR lookahead computation is much more specific than follow set computation.

Comment: But anyway: no complicated graph algorithm comes into it. If the grammar permits a transition, it's in the parsing table. If you compute a parsing table with multiple entries in a cell, it means that grammar wasn't suitable for parsing using the lookahead distance and construction algorithm you choose.